# How can we register test company on Facebook to enable in app purchases?

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, payment

I want to integrate Facebook payments in my app, but it requires detailed company information with all the bank information so I am wondering is there any way to register a test company on Facebook which does not require additional information so I can test in app purchase? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don’t think there is, the documentation doesn’t mention anything in that regard.

Comment: I've contacted their support department as well, yes they doesn't support test company creation. Thank you dear.